# Lightbox beyond the browser

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, fullscreen, lightbox2

I'm working on a new project, a web application, where I need to focus the user on a particular task. Therefore I want to eliminate all other "System Generated Noise", like Browser Menus, Buttons, Address Bar, OS Task Bar and so forth. I have seen implementations like Lightbox, but this modal approach is limited to the size of the browser window.

What I want to do is have the same effect but stretched out beyond de browser so it covers the WHOLE screen. Well, at least that is the effect I'm aiming for.

The application is already on its way, it is being developed with PHP5, XHTML and Javascript/AJAX.

Please, if someone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help you:

http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JavaScript-Maximize-Browser-Window-To-Screen

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it is possible in the way you are describing without using something like flash or silverlight.

With good reason, there are certain things that remote javascript can't, and just shouldn't be able to do.

Another thing to consider are what happens when people have more than one screen, are you going to obscure whats on them too?
Please don't... drives me (and many other people) nuts when a web site tries to resize the browser window, let alone try to run outside of the browser chrome and cover up my task bar.

Let us know what browser you make that work in, and I'll be sure to either cripple the functionality or uninstall it if I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight has a full screen mode that you can set after the first page is rendered in the browser.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/17/tip-trick-supporting-full-screen-mode-with-silverlight.aspx

Don't know if that helps with your current stack:

> PHP5, XHTML and Javascript/AJAX

Keith

Comment: This resembles in part what I need. It's like youtube's fullscreen mode. But Silverlight and Flash are somewhat similar and both require the user to download. I need a somewhat simpler implementation that uses the stack I have available.

Comment: Oh! And Thanks!! I feel like getting closer to the solution needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've been looking around for other options, or alternate ways I can do this. One solution I found, only works with Firefox 2.0+ or IE6+, is to toggle the browsers Full Screen mode. Maybe even do a little pro Open Source and support only Firefox and urge the user to get that browser...but hell, if I'm telling the user to get stuff why not tell it to go and grab Flash o Silverlight, right??

I think it's a thin line between what is possible, what is wanted, and what is right for the user. I've yet to find what is needed to do this. But I think it's a lot more viable option.

> Let us know what browser you make that work in, and I'll be sure to either cripple the functionality or uninstall it if I can't.

Mmm WTF!? Gonna go ahead and asume that was a nice comment gone bad. Not very constructive though.

Comment: Good Luck, but a browser that allows javascipt to overrun the chrome would be a very bad thing.